# 403 Forbidden .The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it

Tags: php, soap, jdeveloper, nusoap

im trying to deploy my mobile application but i can't get a connection from my nuSOAP web service .

Im using jdeveloper MAF 12c and php.

When i click to the button i get this error

[image]

Translation :  **403 Forbidden The server understood the request, but is refusing to fulfill it. Authorization will not help and the request SHOULD NOT be repeated**

Here is the logs when i click to the button :

```
D/Proxy Selector(13021): >>> Java_com_oracle_net_ProxySelectorImpl_getProxyForURL0

D/Proxy Selector(13021): >>> Call getProxyForURL

D/Proxy Selector(13021): >>> initDalvikPointers: 0x60a4dce1 0x60a4dcf9 0x60a560a8 0x60a560a4

D/Proxy Selector(13021): >>> attachCurrentThreadToDalvik: Attach returned JNIEnv=0x0x6899c2a4

I/System.out(13021): DalvikProxySelector.getProxyForURL(): No proxy found

D/Proxy Selector(13021): >>> detachCurrentThreadFromDalvik: Detach current thread from dalvik VM

D/Proxy Selector(13021): proxy not found!

D/JVM     (13021): [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - HttpServiceConnection - log] Erreur de connexion : 403

D/JVM     (13021): [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - HttpTransport - parseResponse] RÃ©ponse [Erreur : 403] : <!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//IETF//DTD HTML 2.0//EN">

D/JVM     (13021): <html><head>

D/JVM     (13021): <title>403 Forbidden</title>

D/JVM     (13021): </head><body>

D/JVM     (13021): <h1>Forbidden</h1>

D/JVM     (13021): <p>You don't have permission to access /gcm/MyService.php

D/JVM     (13021): on this server.<br />

D/JVM     (13021): </p>

D/JVM     (13021): <hr>

D/JVM     (13021): <address>Apache/2.4.27 (Win64) PHP/5.6.31 Server at 192.168.1.2 Port 80</address>

D/JVM     (13021): </body></html>

D/JVM     (13021): 

D/JVM     (13021): [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - Utility - invoke] InvocationTargetException Erreur : ERROR [oracle.adfmf.framework.exception.AdfInvocationRuntimeException] - Code d'Ã©tat HTTP 403 Interdit : le serveur a compris la demande, mais refuse d'y rÃ©pondre. Une autorisation serait inutile et la demande ne DOIT PAS Ãªtre rÃ©pÃ©tÃ©e.

I/System.out(13021): [SEVERE - oracle.adfmf.framework - adf.mf.internal - logError] RequÃªte : {"classname":"oracle.adfmf.framework.api.Model","method":"processBatchRequests","params":[false,[{"classname":"oracle.adfmf.framework.api.Model","method":"evaluateMethodExpression","params":["#{SaveDeviceTokenBean.executeinsertUserRegistrationId}",[{".type":"oracle.adfmf.amx.event.ActionEvent"}],"void",["oracle.adfmf.amx.event.ActionEvent"]]}]]}
```

And here is my Connection.xml :

[image]

my httpd-vhosts.conf :

```
# Virtual Hosts # 
<VirtualHost *:80> 
    ServerName localhost 
    ServerAlias localhost 
    DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www" 
    <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/"> 
        Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews 
        AllowOverride All 
        Require local 
    </Directory> 
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: The HTML output code there looks like a standard Apache 403 response but the clue is *You don't have permission to access /gcm/MyService.php* ... so there's either something in the server configuration (httpd-vhosts.conf possibly) or that PHP file that's preventing your service from connecting.

Comment: my httpd-vhosts.conf :# Virtual Hosts
#
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName localhost
  ServerAlias localhost
  DocumentRoot "${INSTALL_DIR}/www"
  <Directory "${INSTALL_DIR}/www/">
    Options +Indexes +Includes +FollowSymLinks +MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Require local
  </Directory>
</VirtualHost>

Comment: something wrong with the file?

Comment: From that, it doesn't *look* like it ... but looking at your Connection.xml screenshot, you're connecting to 192.168.1.2 ... which *could* be your machine but it could be another machine on your local network - I assume that's the httpd-vhost.conf file on 192.168.1.2? If it's a different machine to the one attempting the request, try removing `Require local` (and rebooting Apache of course)

Comment: still the same problem , and i found this : AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/wamp64/www/gcm/MyService.php    in my apache_errors

Comment: Are you trying to connect from another PC

Comment: i didn't understand your question sorry

Comment: i set  Require all granted and all worked fine , Thank you